# JAVA: How to print out 5 , 5.5 , 6.5 , ++

Tags: java, for-loop

I want to make a list of 5 , 5.5 , 6.5 , ++

Can someone show me how to fix it

Here is my code:

```
package com.bowl.Bowling;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (double i = 5; i <= 12; i+=0.5) {
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
5.0 
6.5 
8.0 
9.5 
11.0
```

Comment: Get rid of the `i++;`.

Comment: What is the pattern? Why is the first difference 0.5 and the second 1.0? Is this an arithmetic sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**just delete i++ like here:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (double i = 5; i <= 12; i+=0.5) 
            System.out.println(i);
}
```

in your code, you have two part for update your loop counter which one is `i+=0.5` and another one is `i++` and you should  delete one of them